# In Ag-Grid, how to make a floating row not editable when column is defined as editable?

Tags: ag-grid

In AG-Grid, How to make a floating row not editable when a column is defined as editable?

Is it possible to use floatingCellRenderer to prevent cell editing for the floating row cell?

```
floatingCellRenderer: function(params) {
    if (params.node.floating) {
        do_something_here_to_prevent_this_cell_editing;
    }
}
```

I am using the default cell editors for text/select on the grid.

Answer (score 3):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrmoser/sxg6687d/2/)

all you need to do is make a function that checks whether or not a row is floating:

```
function notFloating (params){
  return !params.node.floating
}
```

then pass that into the `editable` attribute of the affected column