# ag grid apply column definition property for only 1 cell

Tags: angular, ag-grid

How do we use ag grid to enable or disable 'editable' property for only 1 cell?
I know that for styling, for example, we're able to change cell style for only 1 cell in the callback like below:

```
column.cellStyle = function (params) {
  if (some condition) {
       return '{ border: '1px solid red'};
  } else {
      return '{ border: '1px solid green'};
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `editable` attribute:

```
column.editable = function (params) {
  if (params.node.childIndex % 2) {
       return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
```

This example will make it so that every other row is editable.

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41645592/5187323) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42014498/5187323)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't not know we could define callbacks for most column properties